# Data cleaning and splitting text manually into columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-cleaning, data-processing

Using google sheets how can i extract a columns from this data

"aboutYouAnswers" is the first category
there are a set of questions in this category people are answering to from a website, so all the numbers are question numbers ("0"."1" etc)
All the text within the quotes are the answers i would like to convert into individual columns to compare all answers together.

{"aboutYouAnswers":{"0":"eating pizza","1":"lowering the communities IQ","2":"Avax Apes + Origins","3":"ate 100 pizzas in an hour"}}

*image of test data and how it is formatted*
[image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to split text by comma. If so then try `=SPLIT(A1,",")`.

Comment: Hey Ankur Welcome to stackoverflow.com Ensure that you include a sample of a desired outcome in your questions. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(G3:G="",,
 BYROW(G3:G, LAMBDA(rg,
 LAMBDA(l, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, {
               CONCAT(FILTER(l, ISODD(MATCH(l,l,0))=TRUE)&" ",
                      FILTER(l, ISEVEN(MATCH(l,l,0))=TRUE))}))
             ((REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(rg, "\:{(.+)\}}"), ",:")), """","")))))))
```

[image]

### Option 2

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(s, SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(s="",,SPLIT(s, ""&CHAR(10)&""))), " Select Col1 "),"♦"))
             (QUERY({
 IF(G3:G="",,
 BYROW(G3:G, LAMBDA(rg,
 LAMBDA(l, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, {
               CONCAT(FILTER(l, ISODD(MATCH(l,l,0))=TRUE)&"♦",
                      FILTER(l, ISEVEN(MATCH(l,l,0))=TRUE))}))
             ((REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(rg, "\:{(.+)\}}"), ",:")), """",""))))))}, "Select Col1 Where Col1 <>'' ")))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`FLATTEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`CHAR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`CONCAT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592) - [**`FILTER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) - [**`ISODD`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093491) - [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) - [**`ISEVEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093419) - [**`REGEXREPLACE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) - [**`REGEXEXTRACT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: wow thanks, that looks perfect, 
can you check the image in the question of how the incoming data looks like
and what il need to modify in that suggestion

Comment: Just change the range from `A2:A` to `G3:G`

Comment: @AnkurParashar The answer is updated take a look